# Настройка PgAdmin3

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, вот недавно начал изучать рельсы ( вопрос довольно простенький )

и столкнулся с БД PostgreSQL ( и соответственно с PgAdmin )

и возник такой вопрос: как в PgAdmin3 сделать для каждого проекта разные БД, или вкладки - не знаю как правильно назвать )

Вот я создаю 2 проекта ( разных ):

что-то типо

> rails new blog -d postgresql

в Gemfile у меня уже есть gem 'pg'

И открывая database.yml я вижу (и устанавливаю username, password ничему не установлен):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: demitriy
  password:
```

И такой же database.yml в другом проекте.

Потом открываю PgAdmin -> Добавить подключение ->
Имя - local server
port - 5432
имя пользователя - demitriy
пароль (оставляю пустым).

И получаю вот такую картинку:

[image]

Т.е. один "local server" который содержит базы данных двух проектов

Вопрос: что надо поменять (и самое главное где?), чтобы у меня были отдельные вкладки (серверы), которые содержат только один проект

Одна вкладка - для одно проекта,
чтобы иметь - что-то типа:

```
Группы серверов:
  Серверы:
    Blog:
      Базы данных:
        blog_development:
        blog_production:
        blog_test:
    App:
      Базы данных:
        app_development:
        app_production:
        app_test:
```

Comment: Если вы хотите иметь 2 сервера вам нужно их хотябы установить.

Comment: а сделать это можно как ? - "новая регистрация сервера" и изменить "имя" и "имя пользователя" ? ( и пароль оставить пустым ) - и могут ли возникнуть проблемы, если пытаться деплоить на хероку без парольную БД ?

Comment: @DemitriyDN: Поясните, пожалуйста, чего Вы хотите этим добиться и зачем.

Comment: > database: app_development

это и менять

Comment: У меня на компе лежит около 10 разных проектов ( просто я люблю заготовки ), и если я сделаю все заготовки так как описано выше - то получиться, что у меня во вкладке "базы данных"(на рисунке) - будет не семь а 150 разных вкладок...
 Vladimir VG - сейчас попробую

Comment: Так все же, *зачем* Вам 150 отдельных серверов? В чем их преимущество, по сравнению с одним?

Но если очень хотите — меняйте init-скрипты PostgreSQL'а и запускайте. Но сразу предупреждаю, памяти это выжрет — немерено.

Answer (score 1):

Для разработки достаточно одного сервера с кучей баз данных (:
Но если вам нужно поднять несколько серверов постгреса на одном хосте, запустити их на разных портах. А также можно использовать кластеры pg_lsclusters (в том числе и для мультиверсионности).

ps: PgAdmin программа-клиент, вам нужен сервер.

Comment: согласен, для разработки проектов не нужны отдельные сервера,- нужны отдельные базы.